# Making cairo-clock click-through-able (Cairo Graphics)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, xorg

Is there any way that I can make a window on my X windowing system (Ubuntu/Gnome/Compiz) to be click-through? i.e. when I click on it, the click is actually sent to the window beneath it.

The background of this is that I was searching for a decent analog clock for my desktop, and found `cairo-clock` to be what I need, only that I cannot click through it, and there's no option for that. So I am searching for a generic xorg/compiz level solution to this problem, that I can apply on any window of my choice.

Comment: did you ever find a generic solution? I am looking for a way to do this with vlc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying with this specific problem, I came to a solution involving theme SVG files. (`cairo-clock` uses a theme with various `SVG` files).

So the solution was editing the `.svg` files and changing any element opacity to any value below 50%, then re-launching the app! and suddenly all <50% opacity areas are click-through-able!

I believe this behavior is inherited from Cairo graphics framework, and it would apply to other similar situations.

I did a blog post on the issue, for further reading: [Click through "Cairo Clock" widget](http://www.aularon.com/linux/cairo-clock-click-through/).

Comment: Some searching suggested that this is actually a feature of the Compiz plugin "Opacity, Brightness and Saturation" instead of Cairo.

Comment: Just did a `metacity --replace`, now neither transparent nor semi-transparent areas of the SVG files are honored, which is expected. But the strange part is: Click-through-ability is preserved, I can still click-through all pixels that were transparent or <50% transparent!